# How to drop PHP session immediately to /dev/null

Tags: php, session

For testing purposes I want to drop every new session created in PHP, but without errors.

I can't find an elegant way to do this.

- session.save_path=/dev/null is not working, gives error.
- session.save_handler=empty string, defaults to /tmp, session is saved there.
- session.save_handler=false, same as above.
- session.save_handler=NULL, results in an error.
- session.gc_maxlifetime=0 the session will be created for a short time.

Comment: If you used database sessions you could truncate the table. If you're using the traditional file sessions you can flush all the files. I don't think there's a php function or ini setting that will accomplish all this like you're searching for.

Comment: Did you look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php?

Comment: This looks promising, though it has to be done in code, not in configuration. If there's no other option, this could do the trick.

Comment: Maybe changing the session_name? Previous session will not disapear (i think) but all users will need to re-login or start a new session.

Comment: session.save_path="/tmp" (every *nix like OS has world writeable /tmp folder) or from within code: session_save_path(null);. This is quickest dirty way to get round it. But I'd rather refactor the code with testing in mind.